# systemd process stdout/stderr

Tags: logging, systemd, stdout

When I run the service manually, it logs something when it starts.

But I cannot find this log anywhere when it starts as systemd process.

`journalctl -u <service>` only shows the records about the service starting and stopping, not the actual service output.

I tried adding config to `/etc/systemd/system/<service>.service` file:

```
StandardOutput=append:/var/opt/<service>/stdout.log
StandardError=append:/var/opt/<service>/stderr.log
```

but it also didn't help - the files are created after daemon and service restart, but they are empty.

What am I missing?

Thank you for any suggestions, I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 5):

Use the following in the unit file

```
[Service]
StandardError=journal
StandardOutput=journal
StandardInput=null
```

See here for more: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=